# JAVASCRIPT : for loop array undefined -1 index

Tags: javascript

```
var alldivstamp = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i-1].getAttribute("data") > 1){
        //error here = TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined
    }
}
```

error output: "TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined"

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
        if(array[i-1].getAttribute("data") > 1){
            //error here = TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined
        }
    }   
}
```

this did not fix it

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (typeof foo !== 'undefined' && i < 1 && i > array.length-1) {
        if(array[i-1].getAttribute("data") > 1){
            //error here = TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined
        }
    }   
}
```

error here too

*`undefined value in if statement breaks for loop`*

here is the data structure

```
<div class="divs"></div>
<div class="divs"></div>
<div class="divs"></div>
.....
```

> when i=0 it checks for -1 in index
> "therefor array index does not exist cousing for loop to stop"

SOLUTION:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (i > 0) {
        if(array(i-1).getAttribute("data") > 1){
            //do ...
        }
    }if(i == 0){
        //do ...
    }   
}
```

success!

error : (TypeError: "x" is (not) "y")

```
TypeError: "x" is (not) "y"

Examples:
TypeError: "x" is undefined
TypeError: "x" is null
TypeError: "undefined" is not an object
TypeError: "x" is not an object or null
TypeError: "x" is not a symbol
```

Comment: please add the structure of array.

Comment: Not exactly related, but you might get unexpected results, when comparing strings to numbers.

Comment: `alldivstamp !== array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (i > 0) {
        if(array(i-1).getAttribute("data") > 1){
            //do ...
        }
    }if(i == 0){
        //do ...
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14697803)

Comment: this is the solution! error syntax was "TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

According to [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you are getting an array like object with elments.

You could use the index for an access of the item with

```
array[i]
```

and for a property, you could use dot notation, like

```
array[i].foo
```

or bracket notation

```
array[i]['foo']
```

or a method like [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

```
array[i].getAttribute('data')
```

A valid loop, could be this

```
array = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].getAttribute('data')) { // check for truthyness
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your loop does not run. like:

```
 var i = 0; i < array.length; i++
```

but run like this:

```
 var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++
```

perevent from error do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
    var data = array[i];
    if(data){
      if(data.getAttribute("data") > 1){
        // your code
      }
    }
}
```

or

```
for(var i = 1 ; i <= array.length + 1; i++){
    var data = array[i - 1];
    if(data){
      if(data.getAttribute("data") > 1){
        // your code
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in array start from 0. When i=0, array(i-1) equals array(-1) which is undefined. And by the way to get an array value, you use square brackets, not circular brackets . eg. arr[1]

So you should use :

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].getAttribute("data") > 1){
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **first iteration** `i=0`, then `array[i-1]  = array[-1]`. **this is doesn't exists**.

This can be something like this

```
for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i-1].getAttribute("data") > 1){
        //success
    }
}
```

Or

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].getAttribute("data") > 1){
        //success
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You DOM selector returns an array based on your "divs" class. That is the array you need to do your dot length for.

#### UPDATE

You are checking to see if the element has the attribute. You should use the "hasAttribute" method.

Your code....

```
var alldivstamp = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i-1].getAttribute("data") > 1){
        //error here = TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined
    }
}
```

Should be...

```
var alldivstamp = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
for(var i = 0; i < alldivstamp.length; i++){
    if(alldivstamp[i].hasAttribute("data") === false){
        //error here = TypeError: array[(i - 1)] is undefined
    }
}
```